# Bandwidth getting stolen by a user, NetCut safe option? Better option?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, spoofing

I am in a hostel

there must be a user leeching hardcore from time to time. Late at night a group of americans came back, and the bad connection trouble seemed to stop after they went to their rooms.

They must have been leeching something hardcore. I am not gonna teach them how to use torrents or limit their downloads to a reasonable limit.

I browsed the web and saw that NetCut can perform ARP spoofing attacks. Is there someone with experience to this software and can reveal details about it? [The CNET reviews sound pretty horrible if you ask me.](http://download.cnet.com/Netcut/3000-2651_4-30221.html)

Is there another way instead of having to approach a group of teenage US kids and try to explain to them that they shouldn't do what they are doing? I don't have to cut them of completely, just getting my proper share of the connection would be sufficient.

Comment: Ask the network administrator what is happening to cause the slowdown and what can be done to fix it.

Comment: Since you do not manage the free wireless there is nothing you can do from your pc. Notify the the manager at the hostel. They are probably streaming video's or using skype.

Comment: @Paul how many network administrators are in the hostel? yes exactly. None!

Comment: The person you are paying is responsible for ensuring the services you pay for are functioning.  If they cannot or won't then your option is take your business elsewhere, not sabotage other users connections.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can manage your bandwidth is totally dependent on the capabilities of the network equipment that administers the connections.
If you have a home router, it's best that you use QoS to prioritize HTTP over everything else.
Some routers even support limiting the bandwidth and that would make things super easy for you.